# Coding a MultiThreaded Socket Proxy: IOException SocketClosed where it shouldn't

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, proxy

I just started coding a proxy for TCP Socket Connections and although i'm checking if the Sockets are still open i'm getting a IOException. 
This is the LOC which is causing it. Anybody has an idea why this can happen?

```
while (!from.isClosed() && !to.isClosed() && (numOfBytes = in.read(byteBuffer)) != -1)
```

I've already debugged the code; from & to are not closed when they are checked.

for context:

**Proxy.java**

```
public class Proxy
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try (ServerSocket proxyServer = new ServerSocket(5432))
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                Socket client = proxyServer.accept();
                System.out.println(i++);
                Socket server = new Socket("localhost", 5000);
                ProxyHandler clientToServer = new ProxyHandler(client, server);
                ProxyHandler serverToClient = new ProxyHandler(server, client);
                clientToServer.setName("client->server"+i);
                serverToClient.setName("server->client"+i);
                clientToServer.start();
                serverToClient.start();
                System.out.println("proxy started");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**ProxyHandler.java**

```
public class ProxyHandler extends Thread
{

    private Socket from;
    private Socket to;

    public ProxyHandler(Socket from, Socket to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(from.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(to.getOutputStream()))
        {

            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int numOfBytes = 0;
            while (!from.isClosed() && !to.isClosed() && (numOfBytes = in.read(byteBuffer)) != -1)
            {
                out.write(byteBuffer, 0, numOfBytes);
                out.flush();
                System.out.println(getName() + "(" + numOfBytes + ") ");
                System.out.println(new String(byteBuffer, "UTF-8"));
            }
            System.out.println("left : " + getName());
        }
        catch (IOException io)
        {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + io.getMessage() + " " + getName());
            io.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isClosed()` only returns `true` if you, yourself, have explicitly closed the socket. It can not be used to detect unexpected disconnects.

Comment: ah thx, that's new to me. 
Is there a reliable way to determine if a socket was closed by the "other side" ?
The only idea i have is to filter the thrown exceptions.

Comment: @elnin0 If the peer closes the connection, you will get end of stream from a read, which takes various forms depending on which read method you call. It's all documented. In your case `numOfBytes` will be -1: you're already testing it. If you're writing, you will eventually get an `IOException: connection reset'.`